# Prove that $T$ is one to one?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\alpha>0$. Assume that $T:V\to V$ is a linear operator that has the property that
$$
\Vert T(x)\Vert\geq\alpha\Vert x\Vert
$$
Show that $T$ must be one-to-one.

I'm very confused on how to do this one. I don't really understand how to find the length of a transformation. Also I'm confused on how that relates to being one to one. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $T$ is not one-to-one. So we have that $T(x)=T(y)$ for some $x\neq y$.

Then $$ 0=|T(x-y)|=|T(x)-T(y)|\geq \alpha |x-y| > 0$$ since $|x-y|>0$.

That is we have a contradiction. So it is one-to-one.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I don't understand.

Comment: I editted. More concretely which part is problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $T(x)=0$. Then
$$
0=\Vert 0\Vert=\Vert T(x)\Vert\geq\alpha\Vert x\Vert\geq 0
$$
so that $\Vert x\Vert=0$. Hence $x=0$ and $\ker T=\{0\}$.